# AxWindowsMediaPlayer - black component when starts to play movie

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` component in my `WinForm` application. I noticed that when I set URL to file I want to play and call `Ctlcontrols.play()` command there is an eg. 250ms delay before movie starts to play.

During this delay area of `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` is black. This behavior can be very easily seen when you are changing from one movie to another, or just when you stop currently playing movie and start it again.

My current solution is based on postponed `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` visibility set to true when starting to play movie. Player is displayed to user after eg. 500ms when I am sure, movie is actually playing and user will not see black nothing.

I am looking for better way how to avoid black nothing player. Does anyone solved similar issue? Or at least because I am dealing with very empiric values which will be different on different PCs, is there way how create foolproof solution?

`Prereq: WinForms, .NET 4.0, WMP 12 for Windows 7`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnPlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    switch (e.newState)
    {
        case 3: // Playing started
           // Show your control
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first solution, but using this you will not get rid off black screen showing for approx. 200ms before video is actually starts to play. To be honest I still did not found better way how to do avoid my problem than I described in my post

Answer (score 0):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition > axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration - 0.01)
        {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 0;
        }
}
```

this code change currentPosition to 0 second when video running 0.01 milliseconds so that transition effect of black screen can be avoided. But for short videos additional codes needed.